# ExecuteScript doesn't work for localStorage when using variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, local-storage, protractor

I am trying to pass in a variable to use for executeScript as shown below:

```
var groupScript = '\'' + 'localStorage.setItem("groups", "[' + groupNames + ']"); + '\'''
```

which when printed to the console gives me:

```
'localStorage.setItem("groups", "[\\"lunch\\"]");'
```

If I try to run:

```
browser.executeScript( groupScript );
```

It doesn't create the localStorage variable.  However, if I run the following (which just has the value of the variable), it does work:

```
browser.executeScript( 'localStorage.setItem("groups", "[\\"lunch\\"]");');
```

Can someone let me know what I need to do in order to get it to work with passing in the variable?  Trying to create localStorage variable for my protractor test.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special `arguments` array containing the list of arguments passed into a script:

```
browser.executeScript('localStorage.setItem("groups", arguments[0]);', groupNames);
```